# Windows CMake--create a virtualenv and use it in my C++ project embeded python

Tags: python, c++, cmake, windows-10

In my CMakeLists a virtualenv is created and the site-packages are up-to-date. Here is part of my CMakeLists

```
find_program(VIRTUALENV virtualenv)
if(NOT VIRTUALENV)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find `virtualenv` in PATH")
endif()
message(STATUS ${VIRTUALENV})
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT venv
        COMMAND virtualenv venv --python=python.exe
)
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT venv.stamp
        DEPENDS venv requirements.txt
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/requirements.txt requirements.txt
        COMMAND ./venv/Scripts/pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade
)
```

I wanna use the created python env as my python env in my C++ project. When I check the sys.path I found it links to the global python env.  Here is my C++ code

```
PyImport_AppendInittab("emb", &PyInit_emb);

Py_Initialize();        // initialize python interpreter
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys, os");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\"D:/cmake_sourcecode/source_dst\")");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\"D:/cmake_sourcecode/source_dst/python_module\")");
PyRun_SimpleString("print(sys.path)");
```

Here is my sys.path
['C:\Users\Bryan Zoe\Anaconda3\python36.zip', 'C:\Users\Bryan Zoe\Anaconda3\Lib', 'C:\Users\Bryan Zoe\Anaconda3\DLLs', 'D:\cmake_sourcecode\python_dst\Release', 'C:\Users\Bryan Zoe\Anaconda3', 'C:\Users\Bryan Zoe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages', 'C:\Users\Bryan Zoe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\Users\Bryan Zoe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\Users\Bryan Zoe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'D:/cmake_sourcecode/source_dst', 'D:/cmake_sourcecode/source_dst/python_module']

what can I do to make it link the created virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

well, I insert the venv path to sys.path and it works, don't use append, make the venv path with high priority